# error using get_resutls in wordpress custom table

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display the Appnames and AppId columns based on the current user logged in.

```
global $wpdb;
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

$UserId= $current_user->ID;


$siteAppIds = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT AppID, AppNames FROM       
   app_BasicInfo WHERE WpUserId =$UserId, ARRAY_A") );


foreach ( $siteAppIds as $siteAppId) {

echo  $siteAppId-> AppNames;
}
```

any idea what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: is it correct to put `, ARRAY_A` inside the query string? Shouldnt it be the second argument of get_results?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ARRAY_A` and echoing like an `object` try this,

```
$siteAppIds = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT AppID, AppNames FROM       
             app_BasicInfo WHERE WpUserId =$UserId, ARRAY_A") );
foreach ( $siteAppIds as $siteAppId) {
   echo  $siteAppId['AppNames'];
}
```

**OR**

```
$siteAppIds = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT AppID, AppNames FROM       
             app_BasicInfo WHERE WpUserId =$UserId, OBJECT") );
foreach ( $siteAppIds as $siteAppId) {
   echo  $siteAppId->AppNames;
}
```

Read [WPDB Docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)